# Ios Emulator for Windows for flutter

Tags: flutter, android-emulator, flutter-test

I am working on flutter development.
I want to test my created ios application in emulator on Windows laptop is there any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Nope ;)

If you dev for iOS / MacOS target, you need to be on Mac.

iOS / MacOS building need:

- MacOS
- XCode (with cli tools)

Comment: If I have real iphone then can I connect to windows PC and test my Application.Thanks for giving Response 

Comment: Even with an iPhone in USB, you need a MacOS environment to build iOS applications (no matter whether it is with Flutter or another framework)